# How to pass multiple delimiter in Python for BigQuery storage using Cloud Function

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, etl

I am trying to load multiple csv files into a BigQuery table. For some csv files delimiter is comma and for some it is semicolon. Is there any way to pass multiple delimiter in Job config.

```
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    autodetect=True,
    source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV,
    field_delimiter=",",
    write_disposition="WRITE_APPEND",
    skip_leading_rows=1,
)
```

Thanks
Ritz

Comment: No, create 2 jobs or preprocess your files to have a common delimiter

Comment: so does it means that we can't pass multiple delimeter here as in pandas.

Comment: One delimiter per job, no many per job.

Comment: Is replacing `;` to `,`  in the csv-file an option? Then no text-field should contain a `;`, Doing it with a shell command like `sed ` si quite fast.

Comment: yes i replaced it. But now i can see in csv files there is row with extra delimeter like ABC;; ..How to take care of that

Comment: sed is good but i am not sure how i will include in my cloud function that triggers when file arrives in gcs

Comment: I got the solution need to add quote character while loading job ='"' it take care of this

Comment: @turitiw Can you please explain further how you are using quote character to take care of multiple delimiters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deployed the following code in Cloud Functions for this purpose. I am using “Cloud Storage” as the trigger and “Finalize/Create” as the event type. The code works successfully for running Bigquery Load jobs on comma and semicolon delimited files.

**main.py**

```
def hello_gcs(event, context):
 from google.cloud import bigquery
 from google.cloud import storage
 import subprocess

# Construct a BigQuery client object.
 client = bigquery.Client()
 client1 = storage.Client()

 bucket = client1.get_bucket('Bucket-Name')
 blob = bucket.get_blob(event['name'])  

# TODO(developer): Set table_id to the ID of the table to create.
 table_id = "ProjectID.DatasetName.TableName"
 with open("/tmp/z", "wb") as file_obj:

   blob.download_to_file(file_obj)

 subprocess.call(["sed", "-i", "-e",  "s/;/,/", "/tmp/z"])


 job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(

   autodetect=True,
   skip_leading_rows=1,
   field_delimiter=",",
   write_disposition="WRITE_APPEND",
      

   # The source format defaults to CSV, so the line below is optional.
   source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV,
 )
  
 with open("/tmp/z", "rb") as source_file:

   source_file.seek(0)
  

   job = client.load_table_from_file(source_file, table_id, job_config=job_config)

   # Make an API request.
 job.result()  # Waits for the job to complete.
```

**requirements.txt**

```
# Function dependencies, for example:
# package>=version
google-cloud
google-cloud-bigquery
google-cloud-storage
```

Here, I am substituting the “;” with “,” using the `Sed` command. One point to note is while writing to a file in Cloud Functions, we need to give the path as `/tmp/file_name`, as it is the only place in Cloud Functions where writing to a file is allowed. It also assumed that there are no additional commas or semicolons in the files in addition to the delimiter.

Comment: how you are mapping different csv files to tables in Bigquery.For me it is multiple csv files

Comment: This code puts every file that is pushed into the GCS bucket into a Bigquery table. It is not meant to work for pre-existing files in the GCS bucket. If the latter is the requirement then there is no specific need to use Cloud Functions, which gets triggered based on events. About mapping files to various tables, a naming scheme for the files and tables would be required. If you can clarify your requirement, I can edit my answer as per that. Also, please edit the part of the question to reflect your requirement about multiple tables.